# Inner class type parameter bound by enclosing class type variable

Tags: java, generics

Is there any way to use a type variable declared by an enclosing class as a bound on a type variable declared in an inner class?

```
class Test<E> {
   class Inner<T extends E> {}
   <T extends E> void doStuff(T arg) {}
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      new Test<Number>().doStuff(new Integer(0)); // works fine, as expected
      new Test<Number>().new Inner<Integer>(); // won't compile
   }
}
```

javac gives this error:

```
Test.java:6: type parameter java.lang.Integer is not within its bound
             new Test<Number>().new Inner<Integer>();
                                             ^
```

I can't find any combination of types that will satisfy the compiler. What's the difference between the type parameter `T` as declared by `Inner` versus `doStuff`? Why does one work and the other doesn't?

I'm not looking for an alternative, I just want to gain a better understanding of how the language works.

Comment: The example compiles and runs fine for me as written.

Comment: @ILMTitan What compiler are you using?

Comment: Fails on javac 1.6.0_21.

Comment: @axtavt: this is starting to sound like a bug to me.

Comment: Compiled fine for me... Eclipse, JDK 1.6, Mac.

Comment: What you have written here is completely legal and should compile. It compiled without issues on my Eclipse IDE.

Comment: Well, J K, it's apparently a bug in javac 1.6, which of course wouldn't affect Eclipse's compiler. See Bert's answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6557954

```
Bug ID: 6557954
Votes   2
Synopsis    Inner class type parameters doesn't get substituted when checking type well-formedness
Category    java:compiler
Release Fixed    7(b40)
State   10-Fix Delivered, bug
Priority:   5-Very Low
Submit Date 16-MAY-2007
Posted Date : 2008-07-02 16:22:46.0
```

Description

> The compiler fails to accept this program:

```
class Foo<T> {
  class Bar<U extends T> {}
  Foo<Number>.Bar<Integer> f;
}
```

Evaluation

> This is a problem in Check.java as when checking for bound-conformance actual type parameters are subsituted only in topmost type-variable's bound. In this case we have that Foo.Bar is to be checked against the actual type-parameters T=Number, U=Integer

> So it should be the case that:

```
Number <: Object
Integer <: [Number/T]T = Number
```

> unfortunately, javac misses the second substitution so that the check becomes:

```
Integer <: T
```

> which is wrong and cause the error.

***Edit:***

On my system, the code in the question compiles without error with Java 7 `javac`:

```
C:\workspace\Sandbox\src>"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\javac.exe" -version
javac 1.7.0-ea
```

But it fails with the error indicated in the question for Java 6 `javac`:

```
C:\workspace\Sandbox\src>"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\javac.exe" -version
javac 1.6.0_17
```

Comment: @Charlatan - That's how I read it.  I also confirmed on my system - see my edit.