# What does it mean if a variable has the name "this$0" in IntelliJ IDEA while debugging Java?

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea

[image]

I am trying to understand [this](https://github.com/SodiumFRP/sodium) Functional Reactive Java library by running a [test](https://github.com/SodiumFRP/sodium/blob/master/java/tests/java8/sodium/StreamTester.java) called `testSendStream` in debug mode and stepping through the code as the test executes.

The snapshot above shows that there is an oddly named variable called `this$0`.

Where does this name come from ?

What does this name mean ?

Why does this variable has this name ?

What is the reasoning behind giving it this name?

Surely this name does not come from the code itself, it is generated by IntelliJ or javac/java. But why ?

It is also interesting to see what happens if I mark this object by the label `Mystery Object`.

[image]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`this$0` is "hidden field" in `Inner` class (the **non-static** nested class) which is used to hold reference to instance of `Outer` class which was used to create current instance of Inner class.

In short when you have

```
Outer outer = new Outer();
Outer.Inner inner = outer.new Outer.Inner();
```

`Inner` instance held by `inner` will store in its `this$0` field reference to `Outer` instance used to create it (same reference as held by `outer` variable).

It is necessary because nested classes must have access to all members of outer classes (including private ones). If we want to be able to write something like `methodFromOuterClass();` in inner class JVM needs to know on which `Outer` instance it should invoke this method. To make it possible compiler "changes" such code to `this$0.methodFromOuterClass()`.

---

Little more details and example:

```
public class Outer {
    private int id;
    public Outer(int id) { this.id = id;}

    public class Inner{
        void printOuterID(){
            System.out.println(id); 
        }
    }
}
```

Now what will be printed here and why?

```
Outer o1 = new Outer(1);
Outer o2 = new Outer(2);
Outer.Inner in1 = o1.new Inner();
Outer.Inner in2 = o2.new Inner();

in1.printOuterID();
in2.printOuterID();
```

We will see

```
1
2
```

but how `in1` knew that it should print value of `id` from `o1` and not from `o2`?
It is because each instance of inner class knows on which instance of outer class was it created. And that is because of `this$0` reference which stores reference to outer instance used to create inner instance.
This variable is added to all non-static inner classes by compiler and its value is set when you invoke

```
Outer.Inner in1 = o1.new Inner(); //`this$0` will be set to hold `o1` instance.
```

So code like

```
void printOuterID(){
    System.out.println(id); 
  //OR
  //System.out.println(Outer.this.id);
}
```

is compiled into

```
void printOuterID(){
    System.out.println(this$0.id); //although we can't access this$0 explicitly
}
```

---

BTW if your inner class doesn't need to access non-static members of any of its outer classes you may change it to `static class` which will get rid of `this$0` field.

Comment: Maybe worth to mention that an inner class does not need an `Outer.this` and one could make the inner class a _static_ embedded class. Sometimes `static` is just forgotten.

Comment: @JoopEggen Done - assuming I understood you correctly. If I didn't feel free to improve it.

Answer (score 2):

The is a convention related to non static inner classes.  The bytecode of the inner class will contain a reference to a package-scoped field named `this$0` that allows you to refer to the this object of the enclosing class.  Notice in your example `this$0` is the same as the `Mystery Object this` variable defined above it.